# When does the sequence of consecutive derived sets stabilise after a finite number of terms in a metric space?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(M, d)$ be a metric space and $A\subseteq M$. If we define the $n$th derived set by taking the derived set $n$ times, i.e. $((A^\ell)^\ell)^{\ell\dots}$, then, when can we say that the sequence $(A^{(n)})_n$ becomes constant after $N$ finite terms? I looked it up and it seems like this is something to do with the "Cantor–Bendixson rank", but I'm not entirely sure I understand it.

Comment: The Cantor–Bendixson rank of a subset of a topological space is exactly the first ordinal where the sequence of derived sets stabilise, so you question is "what metric spaces has finite Cantor-Bendixsom rank".

Comment: I don't believe there is a nice charactaristic of such property sadly